# How can I build two executables that share a main function in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, organization

I have a project that's becoming large enough that I want to switch to from a plain Makefile to CMake. My project contains only one application, but supports two different boards (each board has a set of source files, and some defines specific to the board). The (simplified) project structure currently looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/
├─ board/
│  ├─ board_a/
│  │  ├─ board.c
│  ├─ board_b/
│  │  ├─ board.c
├─ app/
│  ├─ main.c
CMakeLists.txt
```

I *could* (and currently have) just put everything in the root CMakeLists.txt file, but I don't want that file to become enormous as the project expands. Essentially, I am wondering how I can create a project which allows me to build an executable for either board where each executable can have a separate set of defines (that are used in both the `board.c` and `main.c` files), source files (`board.c` in this case, while sharing the `main.c`), and can share compile/linker options (I want to share some common compilation settings between both executables) without having one enormous `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: When you call `add_executable` you provide list of source files. Just use the same `main.c` in mutliple `add_executable` commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have a `src/CMakeLists.txt`, so you are part of the way there. Put your overall build settings -- dependencies, C standard version, global compiler flags -- in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. In the subdirectories, put only your CMake commands for the executables, or whatever target makes sense locally.

(As an aside, define "enormous"? I've got top-level CMakeLists here that are anywhere between 200-950 lines, but I've seen 3000-line monstrosities as well)

Personally, from the minimal sketch of the source layout here, I'd do:

- `src/CMakeLists.txt` does an `add_subdirectory()` command for **each board**, e.g. `add_subdirectory(board/board_a)` . If you like, `set()` a variable to a list of board names and you can iterate over it.
- In each board's subdirectory, create a library -- shared, static, or `OBJECT` -- named after the board, with the sources for that board. For instance `add_library(board_a OBJECT board.c)`
- Back in `src/CMakeLists.txt` again, for each board, add an executable with the source from `app/` and link to the library defined for the board, like

  ```
  add_executable(exe_board_a app/source.c)
  target_link_library(exe_board_a PRIVATE board_a)
  ```

  If there are special considerations for that executable, set them there as well. Compile flags can be obtained from the library targets (use STATIC then, not OBJECT).

This moves most of the long-lists-of-sources and potentially compile flags to the per-board `CMakeLists.txt` and turns the intermediate level into a long list of "make this executable".

Comment: Jinx! Three practically identical answers in the span of about a minute. That's a first for me on SO. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Not sure if this is outside the scope of this question, but say I add the `CMakeLists.txt` in `src/board/board_a`. If the code in `board.c` depends on some code in say, `src/lib/some_lib`, how can I add that dependency without a hard-coded link to that library?

Answer (score 2):

> how I can create a project which allows me to build an executable for either board where each executable can have a separate set of defines

Put `CMakeLists.txt` inside `board_a` that does `add_library(board_a board.c)`.

Put `CMakeLists.txt` inside `board_b` that does `add_library(board_b board.c)`.

If the boards are somewhat similar:

- In the root `CMakeLists.txt` create a `add_executable(exe_board_a main.c)` that `target_link_libraries(exe_board_a PUBLIC board_a)`.
- Repeat above for `exe_board_b`

If the boards are unrelated, like need many different compiler flags or separate toolchain files or even different compilers:

- In the root `CMakeLists.txt` `add_executable(exe main.c)` that does `target_link_libraries(exe PUBLIC ${USE_BOARD})`.
- Compile your project twice with `cmake -DUSE_BOARD=board_a` and `cmake -DUSE_BOARD=board_b`. Use two separate build directories. The double compilation can be scripted with a custom script, a root custom Makefile, or you can research cmake-presets.

Remember to use `target_*` commands, not the directory specific commands.

Comment: Now we have three answers that say nearly-the-same-thing. And none of us wrote "create a CMake function that does the boilerplate for you, given a board name".

Comment: +1 for the scenario when the boards are unrelated and the recommendation to avoid directory commands. It's way too easy to write yourself into a hole doing that.

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot - that's because IMHO a function is overkill. A loop is plenty and the function won't be reused in other projects or after export.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too bad with object libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(boards LANGUAGES C)

add_library(board_a OBJECT src/board_a/board.c)
target_compile_definitions(
  board_a PUBLIC "defines for board_a.c and main.c")

add_library(board_b OBJECT src/board_b/board.c)
target_compile_definitions(
  board_b PUBLIC "defines for board_b.c and main.c")

add_executable(main_a src/app/main.c)
target_link_libraries(main_a PRIVATE board_a)

add_executable(main_b src/app/main.c)
target_link_libraries(main_b PRIVATE board_b)
```

You could of course move the add_library calls down into subdirectories (via `add_subdirectory`), but the trick I'm using here is to put things like defines on as PUBLIC usage requirements for the object libraries, so that they will propagate to main.c when the associated application compiles.

You would have one `add_executable` call per board in the top level which you could of course place in a loop if you wind up with many boards.